# TKinter canvas X,Y Plotting

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Im wondering if there is a program online or downloadable that allows you to set a desired window size, draw lines to make a drawing and then it prints the origin (x,y) valuses and end (x,y) values for all drawn lines. This would really speed up my line drawing on Tkinter as i dont have to keep doing trial and error to get my lines to match up and join. If there isn't such a program, are there any ways of drawing on a canvas much more quickly than (x,y) trial and error.Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made you a little something :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>
    body {
      height: 3000px;
    }
    
    .dot {
      width: 2px;
      height: 2px;
      background-color: black;
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>Click mouse to start then click again to pause or click clear</div>
  <button id="clear">Mouse over to clear</button>
  <textarea id="results"></textarea>
  <script>
    (function() {
      "use strict";

      var draw = false;

      function clear() {
        $(".dot").remove();
        $("#results").html("");
      }

      function stop() {
        draw = false;
      }

      function start() {
        draw = true;
      }
      $("#clear").mouseover(clear);
      document.onmousedown = start;
      document.onmouseup = stop;
      document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;

      function handleMouseMove(event) {
        if (draw == false) return;
        var dot, eventDoc, doc, body, pageX, pageY;

        event = event || window.event; // IE-ism

        // If pageX/Y aren't available and clientX/Y
        // are, calculate pageX/Y - logic taken from jQuery
        // Calculate pageX/Y if missing and clientX/Y available
        if (event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null) {
          eventDoc = (event.target && event.target.ownerDocument) || document;
          doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
          body = eventDoc.body;

          event.pageX = event.clientX +
            (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) -
            (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
          event.pageY = event.clientY +
            (doc && doc.scrollTop || body && body.scrollTop || 0) -
            (doc && doc.clientTop || body && body.clientTop || 0);
        }

        // Add a dot to follow the cursor
        dot = document.createElement('div');
        dot.className = "dot";
        dot.style.left = event.pageX + "px";
        dot.style.top = event.pageY + "px";
        dot.style.position = "absolute";
        document.body.appendChild(dot);
        var result = event.pageX + "," + event.pageY + "\n";
        $("#results").append(result);
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Just click the mouse and draw on the output and then you can copy the textbox output.

Comment: Not accurate for drawing straight lines but will still work just fine. Awesome, thanks for this. If you can change it to be similar to the line tool in MS Paint rather than a drag to draw thing that would be perfect, but either way this is very useful as is. Thanks :)